# Disect an RSS feed

Tags: iphone, rss

Im having trouble disecting this RSS feed: http://missing.amberalertnederland.nl/nl/index.rss

I want to display the images in a tableview, but the images arent given a seperate tag. How do I extract these images from the description tag? Scan for < and > ?

answer:

```
- (NSString *)getImage:(NSString *)imageString{

NSString *urlImage = nil;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:imageString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"src=\"" intoString:nil];
if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanString:@"src=\"" intoString:nil];
    NSString *urlImage = nil;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:&urlImage];
    if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", urlImage);
    }
}

return urlImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use NSScanner to san up to `src="` than scan to the next `"` and place the result in a temp string.

That should do the trick.